# Quel est le sens de « Les moyens deviennent des fins en soi et l’organisation justifie son existence par ses moyens... »

Tags: sens

Les moyens deviennent des fins en soi et l’organisation justifie son existence par ses moyens et non par les fins qu’elle devrait chercher à atteindre.

Comment: « La fin justifie les moyens » argument totalitaire/antidémocratique qui place le chef/le tyran/le conseil d'administration au-dessus de son peuple tout dévoué à sa cause/la populace besogneuse (pardon, les collaborateurs dévoués qui deviennent plus intéressés par leur carrière que par le service à autrui) à exploiter auxquels on fournit des ennemis étrangers/des limites et obligations privatives de liberté ou de libre-arbitre/des objectifs inatteignable pour en retirer légitimité/pouvoirs/richesses…

Comment: … la quête du Veau d'Or pour y arriver efface/détourne/manipule les esprits/les forces engagé·es dans un projet, au départ, commun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ça me semble clair si l'on prend le mot  moyen dans son sens basique de « technique » :  l'organisation utilise certains moyens pour arriver à ses fins, mais dans le processus de cette utilisation certaines nécessités ou certaines influences ont la conséquence qu'une attention particulière est portée sur les moyens—qu'ils présentent un aspect qui est défectueux, qu'ils soient soudainement peu adaptés ou hors norme, etc.—et alors les efforts de l'organisation divergent pour ne plus se concentrer sur les fins habituelles et pour faire d'une nouvelle activité, c'est à dire celle qu'elle se donne de produire des moyens ou de les améliorer, de nouvelles fins de l'organisation ; si ce processus de divergence entraine l'organisation suffisamment loin, alors  sa raison d'être a été  déplacée, et elle a  besoin de modifier son image et de présenter ses nouvelles motivations.

Si on entend par « moyens » la simple capacité de fournir du capital, c'est aussi clair ; sachant que toute organisation fondée sur le capital se doit de maintenir ce capital, il est clair qu'un effort particulier dans ce sens non seulement préserve le capital, mais le valorise, et une organisation peut passer ainsi d'un domaine quelconque dans le domaine purement financier où le produit final est le capital, les moyens.